# Delete duplicates in a loop?

Tags: loops, abap, internal-tables

I have a table with some data:

```
101
101
102
101
102
103
103
```

and I need to delete duplicates like this:

```
101
102
101
102
103
```

but in this case I cant use `delete adjacent duplicates`.

What can I do?

Comment: Sort the table first, then try the `delete adjacent duplicates.`.

Comment: I'm confused, why can't you use 'delete adjacent duplicates'?

Comment: Becouse, in this case it will delete all duplicates, but I need to delete duplicate rows that goes in a row.

Comment: Have you tried DELETE ADJACENT DUPLICATES? It does exactly what you want, just do not sort the data first.

Answer (score 1):

```
DATA: LS_PREV LIKE LINE OF TAB.
" Set LS_PREV to some value you know will not occur in the table
LOOP AT TAB INTO LS_TAB.
  IF LS_TAB EQ LS_PREV.
    DELETE TAB.
  ENDIF.
  LS_PREV = LS_TAB.
ENDLOOP.
```

or as vwegert points out below:

```
DELETE ADJACENT DUPLICATES FROM TAB.
```

Comment: Why reinvent the wheel when there's a built-in statement for that?

Comment: Because I like reinventing things ;-) No, actually because I never used DELETE ADJACENT DUPLICATES without a sort. I guess the original question is just a bit silly. Tried it with a little test program and it would exactly do what the OP wants.

Answer (score 1):

1. Do not sort the internal table to keep the order of the entries.
2. Use `DELETE ADJACENT DUPLICATES FROM (tableName)`.

Result: Only the entries are deleted that duplicate rows that goes in a row.

Note: Only if you sort the internal table before all duplicates would be deleted.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose your table is: **lt_tab**.
Then

```
LOOP AT lt_tab INTO ls_tab.
  IF ls_tab_prev EQ ls_tab.
    DELETE lt_tab INDEX sy-tabix.
  ENDIF.
  ls_tab_prev = ls_tab
ENDLOOP.
```

Another approach is :
Suppose you have duplicate data in '**DUPCOL**' In table **lt_tab**.

Then,

```
SORT lt_tab BY DUPCOL.
DELETE ADJACENT DUPLICATES FROM lt_tab COMPARING DUPCOL.
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work just fine.

```
REPORT z_teste_brl.

TYPES : ty_n TYPE n LENGTH 3.
DATA  : t_n TYPE TABLE OF ty_n WITH DEFAULT KEY.
DATA  : curr_n TYPE ty_n.
DATA  : last_n TYPE ty_n.

APPEND '101' TO t_n.
APPEND '101' TO t_n.
APPEND '102' TO t_n.
APPEND '101' TO t_n.
APPEND '102' TO t_n.
APPEND '103' TO t_n.
APPEND '103' TO t_n.

LOOP AT t_n INTO curr_n.
  IF sy-tabix GT 1 AND curr_n EQ last_n.
    DELETE t_n INDEX sy-tabix.
    CONTINUE.
  ELSE.
    last_n = curr_n.
  ENDIF.
ENDLOOP.

BREAK-POINT.
```